# Python to Pull Oracle Data in Unicode (Arabic) format

Tags: python, string, oracle, unicode, arabic

I am using cx_Oracle to fetch some data stored in Arabic characters from an Oracle database. Below is how I try to connect to the database. When I try to print the results, specially those columns stored in Arabic, I get something like "?????" which seems to me that the data was not coded properly.

I tried to print random Arabic string in Python it went alright, which indicates the problem is in the manner in which I am pulling data from the database.

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, instanceName)
wells = getWells(connection)

def getWells(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    wells = []
    cursor.execute(sql)
    clmns = len(cursor.description)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
        well = {}
        for i in range(0, clmns):
            if type(row[i]) is not datetime.datetime:
                well[cursor.description[i][0]] = row[i]
            else:
                well[cursor.description[i][0]] = row[i].isoformat()
        wells.append(well)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return wells
```

Comment: OCI _should_ handle this already; what's your OS Environment default language? `print(os.environ['NLS_LANG'])` should display it to you. Mine is `'english_united kingdom.UTF8'`, for instance.

Comment: No problem, do you want to write up a generic answer that explains to others what you had to change?

Comment: @Ben yes of course. Go ahead please

Answer (score 0):

In order to force a reset of the default encoding from the environment, you can call the setdefaultencoding method in the sys module.

As this is not recommended, it is not visible by default and a reload is required.

It is recommended that you attempt to fix the encoding set in the shell for the user on the host system rather than modifying in a script.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```